# PDFSharp Assembly manifest definition

Tags: pdfsharp

I installed PDFSharp/MigraDoc from the Nuget Manager and tried using it.  When I try to write a PDF it gives me this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharp, Version=1.32.3057.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It gave me an assembly load trace, which is as follows:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = PdfSharp, Version=1.32.3057.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jh/Documents/GitHub/Base1.5/Website/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\jh\Documents\GitHub\Base1.5\Website\bin
Calling assembly : MigraDoc.Rendering, Version=1.32.4334.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\jhop\Documents\GitHub\Base1.5\Website\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\jhop\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: PdfSharp, Version=1.32.3057.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jh/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/81f4fd95/d5ff50bc/PdfSharp.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jh/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/81f4fd95/d5ff50bc/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jh/Documents/GitHub/Base1.5/Website/bin/PdfSharp.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: We can't help you without your code. Please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the MigraDoc packages include PDFsharp, so do not install both PDFsharp and MigraDoc as separate packages from NuGet.

The different version numbers 1.32.4334 and 1.32.3057 suggest that you installed different and incompatible NuGet packages or maybe reference assemblies that did not come from NuGet at all.